# Sql join or separate queries

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I have movie database. I keep images, videos, reviews, etc in separate tables. So when a movie is viewed i can use table joins and display output. Also possible to do this separately. That is, first query gets movie details, second gets all pictures of this movie, then another gets all video of this movie.

So what i should use?

Table joins first joins the tables and then applies where condition. So is it having more overhead?

Comment: we need more data. Size of tables, numbers of rows estimated on each one, existance of indexes, etc..

Comment: i only started now. It is a movie database. Size of rows would be around 1000 or 10000 in nos. Each movie can have atleast 5 images

Comment: @VppMan The answer depends on the data you need to retreive. If you want your program to show everything in just one action, then a single query should be enough... And about performance... if your database is properly normalized, a single query can be simpler (and at worse as slow) as three separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

When you use joins, MySQL will use temporary tables. As a general rule, if you can avoid these, do it. You ought to do a bunch of different queries and join them in memory.

Answer (score 0):

There is Partition in Sql 2008 for big table. It can seperate by any category